# Sample phonegap build PushWoosh plugin / usage

Tags: cordova, build, notifications, pushwoosh

I want to use the plugin PushWoosh for Phonegap Build (https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/150). In our APP we use PhoneGap build 3.0.0 so it's fully compatible.

I searched the internet for days but someways it isn't clear to me how to implement this plugin succesfully.

What we want to do:
1. When app is started register device (always)
2. Correctly receive pushwoosh messages
3. A button to unsubscribe from push messages

First two are most important.

Is there anybody out there who can make a very simple sample set-up? I think it will be useful for all of us!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Bas

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on a Pushwoosh Sample app for PGB here:
https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-3-sample-app

This file in particular:
https://github.com/shaders/phonegap-3-sample-app/blob/master/www/js/index.js

The sample app supports iOS and Android. You can simply import this github repo into Phonegap Build to get the running version of out the box.

Thanks

Pushwoosh Team :)

Comment: Dear PW-team,
First of all, thanks for your answer!! This helps me very much indeed. When I implement this solution in my app the phone I use for testing does registrate on your service. Besides I receive a notification when I push it eitherway all I see is (Android 4):

Alert - null

How to solve this? Did I do something wrong??

Comment: Thanks for the links.I was also confused totally. This sample app just removed all my conusions.

Comment: If you see alert as "null", please make sure you select "Pushwoosh" in application settings in the Pushwoosh control panel. "Phonegap Build generic" is for GenericPush plugin, not plugin by Pushwoosh.